# Unit testing with mock and patch

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, monkeypatching

I am writing unit tests for a function, f, which imports other functions/classes which the unit test does not (directly) interact with. Is there any way I can patch those functions from the unit test (maybe in set_up())?

For reference, I am using Python 2.7.

From the unittest, I want to modify/patch the behavior of helper.

In unittest file:

```
def test_some_function():
    assert(some_function() == True)
```

In some_function() definition

```
import helper
def some_function():
    foo = helper.do_something()
    return foo & bar
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your scenario. i.e. Show your code and test code and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully that is enough. I don't think there is much more code I can paste, as this is more of a general question. I know that I can patch, etc. within a single file, but I want to be able to change the behaviour for the unit tests. I tried using a set_up() patch command, but could not get it to work.

Comment: So, you want to control what `helper.do_something` does? In other words, you are looking to mock that to control its return to write your unit tests for `some_function`? Because that is definitely doable

Comment: Exactly! My first question was if that was possible, so thanks for clarifying that. :) How can I go about actually doing it? I've tried MagicMock, @patch, etc. based on different blogs, but nothing seems to change the behavior in the unit tests, only locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking out a module is fairly standard and documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide). You will see a fairly explicit example of how it is done.

Furthermore, it is important to understand [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), to understand how you properly mock out modules in other scripts.

To provide you with a more explicit example with reference to your code, you want to do something like this:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import module_you_are_testing

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('module_you_are_testing.helper')
    def test_some_function(self, helper_mock):
        helper_mock.do_something.return_value = "something"
        # do more of your testing things here
```

So, the important thing to remember here, is that you are referencing `helper` with respect to *where* you are testing. Look at the sample code I provided and you will see we are importing `module_you_are_testing`. So, it is with respect to *that* you mock.